# Lambda code signing: how to get code signature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, code-signing

My question is, after signing a lambda function, how can i get the lambda code signature? Because I can't find it.

I created a lambda function using AWS Lambda and signed it using AWS Signer. When deploying the lambda function on my greengrass device i have a file called "aws_signer_signature_v1.0.SF". The content of the file has a leaf certificate. Is it possible that it contains the signature of the code? Or the signature offered by thins certificate is to prove that it has been signed by an Intermediate CA? Because I can't tell.

Here is the aws_signer_signature_v1.0.SF file:

```
Certificate:
    Data:enter code here
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            35:04:ad:c6:8d:07:66:c1:1c:50:87:66:6f:b0:b3:d5
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: C=US, O=AWS, OU=Cryptography, ST=WA, CN=Signer us-east-2 SUBORDINATE CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 16 14:19:24 2021 GMT
            Not After : Apr 19 15:19:24 2021 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=WA, L=Seattle, O=AWS, OU=Cryptography, CN=signer
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (384 bit)
                pub:
                    04:9f:e4:bf:41:35:25:af:9c:6b:d8:5c:10:7e:ff:
                    24:29:b1:b5:52:c1:fb:a9:49:b4:87:a8:0a:08:b6:
                    25:91:49:d2:c5:18:9c:9e:3e:52:f4:df:4e:e5:62:
                    d3:37:73:2e:25:b8:84:0b:6b:d1:bd:35:5c:0c:3a:
                    60:8c:60:fd:42:bf:b0:fd:e4:eb:a7:68:80:46:29:
                    a6:39:33:fa:c3:19:34:e2:5d:40:dd:fa:26:bb:ee:
                    89:0d:00:f8:3b:53:4f
                ASN1 OID: secp384r1
                NIST CURVE: P-384
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:08:5B:CC:19:5F:CC:FA:E9:A1:C7:C4:82:1A:90:A1:CF:0F:5F:69:B7

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                E9:D0:4A:3A:8C:94:FE:E9:93:C0:76:5B:DA:21:E4:8A:D8:A0:D6:D4
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                Code Signing
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
         30:64:02:30:1c:2c:86:36:95:47:93:81:35:1f:1f:4a:b4:55:
         7c:30:8c:9a:9e:27:e4:08:50:cc:da:78:cc:c1:f5:6d:8f:87:
         77:ce:0e:5d:b4:6e:c5:dc:5e:42:9d:f6:2b:c3:31:bb:02:30:
         2f:85:dc:98:2f:bc:ec:e2:0d:0a:46:88:ed:11:ba:07:14:e3:
         98:36:6c:30:80:0d:71:c0:e0:6d:97:25:e4:04:58:86:3a:11:
         fe:84:a6:5e:af:4a:01:eb:5b:d2:16:84
```